# How to add border colour animations for `a` elements?

Tags: css, css-animations

I was setting up a logo which contains borders and I used an `a` element but the border animations do not work, they stay how they were stated; how would I make it so that the border colour can change in an animation?

Animation works perfectly with `div` elements

Example:

```css
.anim {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 10px solid #F44336;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: borderanim 1s ease infinite;
          animation: borderanim 1s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes borderanim {
  0% {
    border: 10px solid #F44336;
  }
  100% {
    border: 10px solid #2196F3;
  }
}

@keyframes borderanim {
  0% {
    border: 10px solid #F44336;
  }
  100% {
    border: 10px solid #2196F3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim"></div>
<a class="anim" href="/"></a>
<br/>
<a class="anim" href="http://google.com/"></a>
<a class="anim" href="http://codepen.io/"></a>
<a class="anim" href="http://backpack.tf/"></a>
<a class="anim" href="javascript:location.href='http://codepen.io/';"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey OfficialAntarctica.

It's because the `href` tag is empty. It must be populated or there must be no `href` attribute at all.

I put together a jsBin showing this behaviour [here](http://jsbin.com/xiloradohi/2/edit?html,css,output) and when the `href` attribute was empty the animation wouldn't run until I placed a dummy link in there.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin:  0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.anim {
  display: inline-block;
  border : 5px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  animation: animateBorder 1s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes animateBorder {
  from {
    border: 5px solid red;
  }
  to   {
    border: 5px solid blue;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateBorder {
  from {
    border: 5px solid red;
  }
  to   {
    border: 5px solid blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <a class="anim" href="/link.com">I am an animated link.</a>
  <a class="anim" href="">I won't animate.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps you out!

**UPDATE::** After further investigation, the desired behaviour currently won't work in Chrome. It works in Firefox. I did try using pseudo elements to see if that would make it possible but it seems the only Chrome work around would be to wrap your links in say a `span` element and animating that.

Comment: Thank you, however a link to an external website won't work `<a class="anim" href="http://codepen.io/">I am meant to be an animated link.</a>` for example will not animate

Comment: Wow, that's some strange behaviour indeed. Because, for instance `http://google.com` works fine. `.com` works cool but `.io` plays up...

Comment: Yeah, I'm also linking to websites with .tf endings and they have the same problems

Comment: A hacky way round it might be `onclick = "window.location = 'http://codepen.io'; "` Haha. Certainly not ideal but might work.

Comment: It'll do for now at least cx

Comment: Original answer works in Firefox so is an acceptable answer. There is a bug I believe with how Chrome picks it up.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `href` value seems to resolve the situation.

```css
.anim {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 10px solid #F44336;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: borderanim 1s ease infinite;
          animation: borderanim 1s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes borderanim {
  0% {
    border: 10px solid #F44336;
  }
  100% {
    border: 10px solid #2196F3;
  }
}

@keyframes borderanim {
  0% {
    border: 10px solid #F44336;
  }
  100% {
    border: 10px solid #2196F3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim"></div>
<a class="anim" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

Comment: But how would I link to another webpage?

Comment: You can set the link to any other web pages. The problem is `href=""`

Comment: Still got problems (see OP)

Comment: That's really strange! As it's said above, `<a class="anim" href="javascript:location.href='http://codepen.io/';"></a>` can be workaround for now...